Delta frameless sliding contemporary shower
I am installing this shower door in a 3 piece shower inclosure. I followed the directions with putting 2 each 2x6’s on the edge. My question is the instructions say you must use the provided anchors when installing the wall jamb but there is wood there. So this means I do not have to use the provided anchors? Right? It’s a simple question but I don’t want to mess this up.
Thanks

I’m pretty sure I don’t need them and this might be a silly question but just wanted to put it out there

I can’t upload a picture of the instructions cause it’s too big but when I framed out the walls when installing the shower walls it said to add 2 of the 2x6’s sticking out enough for support of the shower door.

I think I pretty much have answered my question because I do have an anchor point and it’s the 2x6

If you can put the screw into wood, that's better than the anchor.

Those are pretty lousy anchors. You don't need them. Just seal around the screws to prevent moisture from seeping in behind them.
